# what is a switch default gateway

Tags: cisco

I have two questions, please help

1. layer 2 switch doesn't know how to routing, but if I set the default 
   gateway in the switch, how can it "routing" or how can it forward the packet
   to the default gateway?
2. when i connect a PC to a swtich, and the switch set a vlan 1 
   management IP (for example 192.168.1.2), then PC ping the switch,
   firstly, the PC will use arp to find the switch's mac address? but 
   how can a layer 2 switch handle the arp, to tell the PC that i am 
   (192.168.1.2 and mac address is XX.XX.XX.XX)?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you are talking about a managed switch.

1) You set the default gateway because the switch has an IP address for remote management.  If you do not set a default gateway then you would only be able to manage the switch from a system on the same subnet.  Just like your pc; it is not routing anything at the IP level.

2)  The layer 2 switch can handle the arp because it has an IP address for management.  It will behave like any other properly functioning client on a TCP/IP network.

Comment: Adding to 1: ROUTING packets (for connected computers) has nothign to do with the switch being a participant in an IP Network as a "client" (I.e. it has an IP address, same as a normal computer).

Comment: but how can a switch handle a arp, it is only layer 2 switch and it can't handle layer3, how to tell the PC i am (192.168.1.2 and mac address is XX.XX.XX.XX)?

Comment: i am very confusing about how can the layer2 switch reply the arp reply to the PC when they communicate firstly?

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion is coming from.  Just because the device is designed to direct network traffic at layer 2 doesn't in any way prevent it from participating in higher layers for other purposes.  At layer 2 it's directing traffic, above that it's a client.  Why should a layer 2 switch behave differently? How would you expect to manage it?